# How to test immutable Map using React Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, immutable.js

I have an immutable Map:

```
const defaultStore = {
    getState: () => fromJS({
        properties: {
            prop: {
                name: 'Name',
            },
        }
    })
};
```

I would like to test it using Jest/Enzyme but I can't change `name` prop. What is the proper way to test immutable Map?

Comment: what exactly are you going to test here? do you want to test immutability?

Comment: @skyboyer I want to test if user can go to the next step. To do this, he has to type something into input so I want to make test with and without `name` property. However I can't change it using .set method or setProps method.

Comment: do you want to test store or component? I did not get it.

Comment: @skyboyer I want to test component - this defaultStore object is just props that I'm passing to it and as you can see this is an Immutable Map. I want to simulate change to `name` property which has 'Name' value at the beginning (change it into empty string and test if user can pass this step or not)

Comment: you can pass different store that has different value. can you add minimal working version of component to test?

Comment: @skyboyer This component and props are way bigger than what you can see here. You suggest that only way to test it with different props is to pass new store every time? setProps method is creating new 'name' prop and I want it to be merged into old 'name' prop.